# Setting Values in a variable as Dictionary

Tags: javascript

I have a set of values for a DropDownList. My requirement is before setting on the DropDown, values need to be stored in a javascript variable using loop in the below format:

```
var categories = [{
                "value": 1,
                "text": "Keyboard"
            },{
                "value": 2,
                "text": "Mouse"
            },{
                "value": 3,
                "text": "Monitor"
            }];
```

I created a sample like below:

```
dataType: "json",
data: { categoryId: CategoryHdId },
success: function (data) {
                var categories = [];
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    case = {
                        "value": data[i].ddlSubCategoryId,
                        "text": data[i].SubCategoryName
                    }
                    categories.append(case);
                }
}
```

But this gives a

`Syntax Error`

and

`Uncaught TypeError: categories.append is not a function`

Can anyone help how to set them inside the loop.

Comment: Use push function in place of append. Check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`case` is a reserved word in javascript so you can't use it as a variable name, use some other variable name. Also use `push()` to add values to an array.

```
dataType: "json",
data: { categoryId: CategoryHdId },
success: function (data) {
                var categories = [];
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                   // case = {  reserved word case will throw syntax error  
                      someVar = {      //declare as var if you don't want it to be global                 
                        "value": data[i].ddlSubCategoryId,
                        "text": data[i].SubCategoryName
                      }
                    categories.push(someVar);
                }
}
```

Comment: I think you should change `categories.append(case);` too.

Comment: I'd also recommend declaring `someVar` so that it's not creating a global object.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein can't say what the requirement really is, what if the OP wants to make it a global object

Comment: @Dij Fair enough!

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
var categories = []; 
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    categories.push({ "value": data[i].ddlSubCategoryId, "text": data[i].SubCategoryName })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataType: "json",
data: { categoryId: CategoryHdId },
success: function (data) {
                var categories = [];
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    let temp = {
                        "value": data[i].ddlSubCategoryId,
                        "text": data[i].SubCategoryName
                    }
                    categories.push(temp);
                }
}
```